# Web Scrape using php curl

Tags: php, html, json, curl, web-scraping

I have a html page that has the following code. Now I want to print only name and location in my local page in json format.

```
<div class='post-header'>
<div class='post-header-line-1'></div>
</div>
<div class='post-body entry-content' id='post-body-210098160524748093'   itemprop='articleBody'>
<div class="separator" style="clear: right; float: right; margin-bottom: 1em; margin-left: 1em; text-align: center;">
<br /></div>


<br />
<br />
<ul>
<li>Name<br />Location</li>
<li>Name<br />location</li>
<li>name<br />location</li>
<li>name<br />location</li>
</ul>
<br />
```

The output should be like this, any suggestion will be helpful.

```
{
"contacts": [
    {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Name",
            "location":"location"
    },
    {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Name",
            "location":"location"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: load the page thru curl, then use DOMDocument, then gather the node values inside an array, then finally use json encode

Answer (score 0):

You could grab content of the `<li></li>` elements, split them by `<br />` and then generate the JSON by using jQuery, then pass it to PHP by using jQuery `POST` request method:

```
$().ready(function() {
    var storeLocations = new Array();
    var storeName = new Array();

    $("li").each(function() {
        var content = $(this).text().split('<br />');
        storeName[storeName.length] = content[0];
        storeLocation[storeLocation.length] = content[1];
    });

    var jsonString = '{["contacts:["';

    for(var i = 0; i < storeLocations.length; i++) {
        jsonString += '{"id:' + i + ', "name:"' + storeName[i] + '", "location:"' + storeLocation[i] + '"},';
    }

    jsonString += "]]}";
    var url = "form.php";

    $.post(url, jsonString);
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: the `jquery` tag isn't included on the question, but anyway, no need to build the json string by hand, just use `JSON.stringify(javascript_object)`, would be the best use in this case if you want a json string, or just the whole object instead, and let PHP decode it

Comment: I understand, I do not know how to grab page elements directly from the page by using PHP so I offered next idea that came to my head. Thanks for an info.

Answer (score 0):

Another method would be to do it with regular expressions

```
<?php

$re = '/<li>([a-zA-Z]+)<br \/>([a-zA-Z]+)<\/li>/m';
$str = '<li>Name<br />Location</li>
<li>Name<br />location</li>
<li>name<br />location</li>
<li>name<br />location</li>';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

$arrayOfResults = [];

foreach($matches as $n => $match) {
    $arrayOfResults["contacts"][] = [
        "id" => $n + 1,
        "name" => $match[1], 
        "location" => $match[2]
    ];
   
}

$json = json_encode($arrayOfResults);

var_dump($json);
```

Here it is on regex101:

https://regex101.com/r/0Hx6qD/1